# IntelliJ IDEA не показывает лампочки-ошибки до компиляции

Tags: java, ide

В документации для IntelliJ IDEA прочитал, что "Инспекции и быстрые исправления
Когда IntelliJ IDEA обнаруживает потенциальную ошибку, в редакторе появляется значок лампочки. Нажмите на него или используйте сочетание клавиш Alt+Enter, чтобы посмотреть список возможных исправлений."
Однако, как бы я не старался разбирать настройки IDE, как бы я не искал в интернете ответов - эта функция не работает вообще никак и никогда.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужна Ваша помощь решить эту проблему.

Comment: Странно как-то idea выглядит. У меня, правда, стандартное отображение, я даже шрифт не менял никогда... Версия актуальная? 2020.2.4?

Comment: А у меня [работает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUO90.png), ищите прблему у себя.

Comment: @Zhenyria, версия 2020.1

Comment: @Zhenyria, IDE поддерживает импорт Eclipse Color Theme, которые можно выбрать на любой вкус из тысяч любую. Settings->Editor->Color Sceme->Знак шестеренки ->Import Scheme->Eclipse Color Theme(XML) и выбираешь скаченную тему  - например отсюда http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Comment: @СаломатинГ.С. посмотрю, спасибо. Хотя я больше приверженец стандартных оформлений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решается отключением "Power Save Mode" - File->Power Save Mode.
Т.е. стояла галочка для этого режима - и лампочки и предупреждения не отображались.